# Will Web Forms Application_BeginRequest Always Fire Before Application_AuthenticateRequest, even if One is in Module and the Other in Global.asax?

Tags: module, webforms, global-asax

In my **Web Forms** application, I am referring to a **module** that has event **Application_BeginRequest** (but does not have **Application_AuthenticateRequest**).

In the **Global.asax** file of my application, I have the event **Application_AuthenticateRequest** (but not **Application_BeginRequest**).

I know the normal order of events is for Application_BeginRequest to be fired before Application_AuthenticateRequest. Can I assume that will be the case for my situation noted above?

Comment: Yes, all BeginRequest handlers are raised before all AuthenticateRequest handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on this Michael.